# Select Multipe in HTML Accessibility

Tags: html, select, accessibility

Is select with the multiple attribute accessible? Either using W3C or with Section 508 compliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select elements with multiple are keyboard navigable but I think a friendlier option for both screenreader and regular users is to use checkboxes wrapped in a `<fieldset>` and include a [`<legend>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-legend-element.html)